# Deserializing objects with gson, Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

Tags: java, android, json, gson

i'm working on deserialization of feed coming from server. I have encountered a weird issue with Gson library. I'm using code i've found here on stack on similar issue thread, but it doesn't work.

Class:

```
package com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.model;

/*t*/

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FeedItem {
    private String username;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    private String id;

    private int stage;
    private int category;

    private double cost;

    private boolean completed;

    private ArrayList<Attendant> attendants;

    private Location loc;

    private Timestamp createdAt;
    private Timestamp expireAt;

    public FeedItem(String username, String title, String description, String id, int stage, int category, double cost, boolean completed, ArrayList<Attendant> attendants, Location loc, String createdAt, String expireAt) {
        this.username = username;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
        this.stage = stage;
        this.category = category;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.completed = completed;
        this.attendants = attendants;
        this.loc = loc;
        this.createdAt = new Timestamp(Long.valueOf(createdAt));
        this.expireAt = new Timestamp(Long.valueOf(expireAt));
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Json:

```
    [{
    "username": "q",
    "title": "123213321213",
    "description": "213",
    "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [0, 0]
    },
    "category": 0,
    "cost": 123,
    "stage": 0,
    "attendants": [],
    "completed": false,
    "id": "553f4f272300001b004f4078",
    "createdAt": "1430212391230",
    "expireAt": "1437599771230"
}, {
    "username": "q",
    "title": "123213321213",
    "description": "213",
    "loc": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [0, 0]
    },
    "category": 0,
    "cost": 123,
    "stage": 0,
    "attendants": [],
    "completed": false,
    "id": "553f4f282300001b004f4079",
    "createdAt": "1430212392752",
    "expireAt": "1437599772752"
}]
```

Unfortunately i don't know where the problem is... Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
public static ArrayList<FeedItem> parseFeed(String toParse){
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<FeedItem>>(){}.getType();
        ArrayList<FeedItem> outcome = new Gson().fromJson(toParse, collectionType);
        return outcome;
    }
```

Error

```
05-09 13:22:06.575    2554-2554/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lanceit.haito.lanceit, PID: 2554
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1430212391230
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:81)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:66)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$22$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:526)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$22$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:524)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
        at com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.utils.SerializationHelper.parseFeed(SerializationHelper.java:55)
        at com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.network.lanceHandler.ListAllLances$1.onResponse(ListAllLances.java:39)
        at com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.network.lanceHandler.ListAllLances$1.onResponse(ListAllLances.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1430212391230" (at offset 13)
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:571)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:79)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:66)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:41)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$22$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:526)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$22$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:524)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
            at com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.utils.SerializationHelper.parseFeed(SerializationHelper.java:55)
            at com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.network.lanceHandler.ListAllLances$1.onResponse(ListAllLances.java:39)
            at com.lanceit.haito.lanceit.network.lanceHandler.ListAllLances$1.onResponse(ListAllLances.java:29)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: Try with: `Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<FeedItem>>(){}.getType();`

Comment: paste your Json String most porbably it is a format issue

Comment: @Blackbelt yea, tried it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @HusseinZawawi Here you go, pasted in the main post that everyone would see it.

Comment: @haito you cant deserialize a long date value to timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json array format is not correct because of that you are getting the above exception. You have a lot of extra properties and some of your properties doesnt match the model types:

Code to generate Json format:

```
 public static String parseFeed(ArrayList<FeedItem> list) {
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<FeedItem>>() {
        }.getType();
        String outcome = new Gson().toJson(list, collectionType);
        return outcome;
```

Valid Format:

```
[{"id":"id1","title":"title1","description":"desc1","createdAt":"Jan 1, 1970 12:00:00 PM","expireAt":"Jan 1, 1970 12:00:00 PM","lat":1.0,"lng":1.0,"cost":10,"category":1}]
```

Comment: Ok.. I see. Do you have any idea how to flatten that id?

Comment: Create a seperate class called id with a property called $oid and update FeedItem to have this new type

Comment: @haito this answer your question plz mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Error occurred because of the root object, Since your root object doesn't contain an direct array, the array is mapped by the "feeds". So you need to create another Bean object for accessing those array.

```
public class FeedsList {
    List<FeedItem> feeds;
    String timestamp;
}
```

Now the json can be parsed by using

```
 FeedsList feedsList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonSample, FeedsList.class);
```

But still you need to modify the data types of some variables in  `FeedItem` because `id`, `loc`, `expireAt`.. etc are declared as `String`'s in `FeedItem` but in the given json they are declared as `JsonObject`'s